# Can I call a method before a constructor

Tags: java

I know I can call static methods inside a constructor.

1. I have one contructor in one class which is calling another constructor through `this(arguments)`.
2. Secondly that second constructor is calling `super(arguments)` calling super constructor.

I want to execute some code before these constructors execute.  I cannot use a `static` block. Any ideas?

Comment: Where are you calling your constructor from? Couldn't you just execute the code before you call the constructor?

Comment: that's not about static block. The super or alternate constructor calling has to be the first statement.

Comment: Also: *"I cannot use static block."* - why? Adding some context and some sample code to your question might help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can call static methods. I often do it like this:

```
public class MyClass extends SuperDuperClass {

  public MyClass() {
    this(convert("Foo!"));  // convert will be executed 
                            // other constructor is called
  }

  public MyClass(String arg) {
    super(convert(arg));  // convert will be executed 
                          // before superconstructor is called
  }

  private static String convert(String arg) {
    return arg + "_modified";
  }
}
```

Of course, we can't call instance methods or use non static fields.

(and, of course, this pattern requires a constructor on super that takes parameters)

Comment: Thanks.But in your code you use super(convert(arg));.Super will search for super metho.My method is in that base class itself.

Comment: replace `super(..)` with `this(..)` - it makes no difference. The static method is called before any other constructor.

Comment: Thanks again.But as you can see in my question.One costructor has this and another constructor has super already.I cant use 2 this or 2 super.Right ?

Answer (score 4):

The `super()` call has to be the first statement in a constructor, no exceptions apart from statics which you've already mentioned you can't use.

Even when you don't explicitly write a `super()` call at the start of your constructor, the compiler puts it in for you. It's always there!

Your best bet is to refactor your code so you don't feel the need to call anything before the `super()` call, but without seeing the code (or at least more context behind it) no-one can tell you how is best to do that!

Comment: The initialiser runs after the call to `super()` returns, so unlikely to be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can't - the first thing java needs is a super.constructer call - written or not!

Answer (score 1):

Use the factory pattern so you can do this:

```
public static MyObject newInstance() {
    staticMethod();
    return new MyObject();
}
```

Assuming the static method isn't supposed to actually change how the constructor behaves, that will literally call it before the constructor is executed.

Comment: My function need a argument which is coming inside Contructor only as it's argument.

Comment: no static method could be use according to the question so I think that @berry120 idea of refactor might be more handy

Answer (score 1):

You can do this, also without a static block:

```
public Main() {
    System.out.println("Inside Constructor");
}

{
   System.out.println("Before Constructor");
}

public void doTest() {
    this.doTest();
}
```

Comment: First understand before replying.